# jQuery: how to join 2 results of requests to json server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, service, request

I wonder if we can do something like

```
 var joinedJSON;
 $.get("server.json?action=type&type=image", function(json) {joinedJSON +=json ; }
 $.get("server.json?action=type&type=jpg", function(json) {joinedJSON +=json ; }
 $.get("server.json?action=type&type=png", function(json) {joinedJSON +=json ; }
 $.get("server.json?action=type&type=tiff", function(json) {joinedJSON +=json ; }
```

while each request will provide us with say such JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "href": "bf051e8675b11c72eec781e855593589a086d2295378b96a8b7269c31b8fa673.user.file",
        "title": "Привет Мир.jpg",
        "user_name": "Oleg.Jakushkin@gmail.com",
        "modified": "2012-01-16 07:24:11",
        "is_public": 0,
        "size": 65516
    },
    {
        "href": "abd01be9a0830579d6366e48fc0c48d4c7cc350d80719843ca84c782346626f6.user.file",
        "title": "",
        "user_name": "Oleg.Jakushkin@gmail.com",
        "modified": "2012-01-16 07:24:19",
        "is_public": 0,
        "size": 89782
    },
    {
        "href": "0a27fd3b563b2877c3a072648e0f7c2a57539f3aba4ce688c7774eca6b70774e.user.file",
        "title": "Привет Мир 2.jpg",
        "user_name": "Oleg.Jakushkin@gmail.com",
        "modified": "2012-01-16 07:24:29",
        "is_public": 1,
        "size": 58574
    }
]
```

Will we get one long array having in mind that some items may repeat (multymap in C++) as result?

Comment: In principle you can do this. However, you will likely have to manually write some glue code. In particular, since JSON data does not enough semantics to allow this to be done automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the add operation `+` on Arrays are not defined in Javascript. Instead of extending an array by another one, it coerces them into strings and concatenated.

```
[1,2,3] + [4,5,6] // will produce '1,2,34,5,6'
```

You should use `concat` instead

```
[1,2,3].concat([4,5,6])
```

Also, note that `$.get` is an asynchronous function. If you simply serialize them in the code you provided, you will not know when all the requests are finished. Instead, you should try to issue each request in the callback function of the previous one. This ensures that each request is made after the the response from the previous one is received.

```
var joinedJSON = [];
$.get("server.json?action=type&type=image", function(json) {
  joinedJSON.concat(json);
  $.get("server.json?action=type&type=jpg", function(json) {
    joinedJSON.cancat(json);
  }
}
```

If you find the nested callbacks ugly, you may consider using [the async module](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you (or your code) parsed the returned JSON strings into arrays you can use .concat() to concat those two arrays into one

```
var jsontotal = json1.concat(json2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make arrays of the responses and merge
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp